# how to replace a string in php

Tags: php

i want to replace '<' and '>' sign in string. 
e.g

```
$str = 'if x<y and y>z';
echo str_replace( '<', 'something', $str ) . "\n";
```

this give the following result

```
if xsomethingy and y>z
```

my question is how can i replace '>' to text 'something'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_replace( array('<', '>'), 'something', $str )
```

is a possibility, see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: how should i replace '>' to other text not specifically 'something'

Comment: and '<' should be replace with 'something'

Comment: thanks RC i have done this by using str_replace(array('<','>'),array('&lt','&gt', $str) and this work for me

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace(/[<>]/g, 'something', $str)`

You need to study some PHP yah 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: how should i convert '<' to &lt and '>' to &gt in the same example

Answer (score 0):

check out `preg_replace()`

Documentation is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

example would be 
`preg_replace('/[<>]/', 'something', $str);`